# Copy files of specific type from parent to child folder

Tags: terminal

I can successfully copy the file from the folder "objects" (the directory I'm in) to it's subfolder "access" with this code in Terminal.

```
find . -name *.pdf -exec cp {} ./access \;
```

But the code is also looking into the "access folder" for files to copy and I get this message

```
cp: ./access/cuid12368.pdf and ./access/cuid12368.pdf are identical (not copied).
```

Is there a way to not have it look into the "access" folder for files to copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` command is not necessary for this operation. Use:

```
cp *.pdf access/.
```

This copies all PDF files to the `access` subfolder and is much prettier and simpler than the equivalent `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files from a folder into a subfolder by simply using the cp command.  For example I have a directory folder1 with 10 PDF files and a folder named folder2. Copy or move the PDF files into folder2 by the following.

```
cd folder1
mv *.pdf folder2/
```

This will move the pdf files to the subfolder folder2.

Comment: The `mv` command above would work the same without the `/` after `folder2`. Use `cp *.* folder2` to copy only all the files directly under `folder1` to `folder2` when inside `folder1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the *find ... -exec cp ...\;* (instead of the *cp*) command and don't want it to walk any subdirectory use the `-maxdepth X` argument.

> ... 0 limits the whole search to the command line arguments (=does nothing).
>   ... 1 limits the whole search to the start directory itself (=no sub-directories).

```
find . -name *.pdf -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} ./access \;
```

In 10.11 El Capitan the previous command failed (*find: example01.pdf: unknown primary or operator*) and I had to use:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} ./access \;
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to not have it look into the "access" folder for files to copy?

Use the `-path "pathname"` arguments.

```
find . -name *.pdf -path "./access" -exec cp {} ./access \;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that tell it to search the folder "access" rather than not search it?